# Is it possible to transpose columns to rows using SQL*Plus formatting only?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I was wondering whether is possible to transpose rows to columns using only SQL*Plus formatting avoiding using UNPIVOT.

Practically, I'd like to add some formatting to this script

```
REM filename query.sql
set heading off
SELECT 'aaaaaaaaaa' A, 'bb' B, 'ccccc' C, 'ddddddd' D from dual;
```

in order to get this output

```
SQL> @query
aaaaaaaaaa
bb
ccccc
ddddddd

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

*If* you know in advance that all values that you will print out are two characters long, then you can simply set `linesize` to `2`:

```
SQL> set heading off
SQL> set linesize 2
SQL> SELECT 'aa' A, 'bb' B, 'cc' C, 'dd' D from dual;

aa
bb
cc
dd


SQL>
```

---

Following you edit of the question, here is a little more generic solution: if you know in advance the maximum size of the string values, then you can format each column to the maximum size (with option `column ... format a<n>`), and set the linesize to the same size, like so:

```
SQL> column A format a50
SQL> column B format a50
SQL> column C format a50
SQL> column D format a50
SQL> set linesize 50
SQL> SELECT 'aaaaaaaaaa' A, 'bb' B, 'ccccc' C, 'ddddddd' D from dual;

aaaaaaaaaa
bb
ccccc
ddddddd


SQL>
```

Comment: Well, that's actually not the case... my question is more generic

Comment: From my point of view, GMB's answer does the job. It is your question, Massimo, that requires an answer which is close to impossible. This is SQL*Plus, after all, not a GUI reporting tool with a lot of capabilities.